# Why is the input string not in the correct format?

Tags: c#

I am using String.Format and keep getting the error: Input String is Not in the Correct Format.

I have tried to eliminate different possibilities, but I cannot find the solution.

The solution must be a simple one, yet I cannot find it.

```
var peanuts = String.Format("{label: '{0}', legendEntry: true, data: { y: [new Date('{1}')], x: [new Date('{2}')], y1: [{3}] } }",
"name", "sync date", "download date", "100");
```

Comment: Seems you try to form a Json string. Why don't you use a real json parser?

Comment: You should use a JSON serializer.

Comment: @Slaks I did look at using a JSON serializer. I do not have an object with these values in my model. I am returning data for a wijmo chart http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=BubbleChart&sample=Overview

Comment: @Robert try this: `var obj = new { label = "name", legendEntry = true, data = new { y=DateTime.Now, x=new[]{DateTime.Now} } };
            string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);`

Comment: @L.B This does not achieve what I need, but you comment re-prompted me to look into using a Json Writer since this is what I am really trying to do. I am going to investigate using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter to achieve what I need.

Comment: @Robert Your question is an exact [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: @L.B Yes, this is what it has turned out to be. :-D I am trying to do something which I do not know how to do. I did think that generating a string was the solution to my problem. Now that my string is working, I realize it is not. Now I have to find another solution. Still, the answer to my actual question at the time is the one marked below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape any `{` characters in your format string, else they will be interpreted as items to be formatted (replaced.)

To insert a literal bracket `{` you double it, like this `{{`.

So your string would be:

```
var peanuts = String.Format("{{label: '{0}', legendEntry: true, data: {{ y: [new Date('{1}')], x: [new Date('{2}')], y1: [{3}] }} }}",
    "name", "sync date", "download date", "100");
```

See the **Escaping Braces** on the [Composite Formatting MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jonathon! This was the solution. Makes sense when you think about it.